# Solve linear system with matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

In my problem, $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix with $m \geq n$ and $\mathrm{rank}(A)= n$. Let $\Gamma$ be the $(m+n) \times n$ matrix defined by :

$$ \Gamma = \begin{bmatrix} A \\ \mathrm{I_{n}} \end{bmatrix} $$

For a given $\mathrm{f} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, I want to solve the linear system :

$$ \Gamma x = \begin{bmatrix} - \mathrm{f} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m+n} \tag{$\star$} $$

In `MATLAB`, I used the `linsolve` function :

```
x = linsolve(Gamma,b); % b=[-f;0];
```

and then, when I compute `norm(Gamma*x-b);` the result is not of the order of `eps`( $\sim 10^{-16}$). I find that `linsolve` fails to produce a "good" solution for my linear system in this case. I also tried `x = linsolve( (A')*A, (A')*b);` but the problem is the same. What am I missing here ? Why can't `linsolve` find a "better" solution to $(\star)$ ?

Here is a reproducible example :

```
m=10;
n=5;
A=rand(m,n);
Gamma=[A;eye(n)];
b=[ones(m,1);zeros(n,1)];
x=linsolve(Gamma,b);
norm(Gamma*x-b)
```

Comment: The system is obviously not consistent: $I_nx=0$ only for $x=0$. You can solve it in the least squares sense (that is what the `linsolve` function probably does) but then you cannot measure the accuracy of the solution by the residual norm in the original problem. You might probably be happy with the residual norm in the normal equation system: $\|A^Tr\|_2/\|r\|_2$ with $r=b-Ax$.

Comment: You have more equations than unknowns; why do you expect to be able to find an exact solution?

Comment: Also, your text specifies $m\geq n$ but your example has $m < n$ (although I don't think this is relevant - probably just a typo).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel : You're right. I should have paid more attention to my problem. My motivation is the following : I would like to find $x$ such that :

$$ \big( A^{\top}A + \mathrm{I}_{n} \big)x = - A^{\top}\mathrm{f} $$

I believe the problem is equivalent to sovling $\displaystyle \Gamma x = \begin{bmatrix} -\mathrm{f} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Note that the first problem are normal equations of the second problem solved in the least-squares sense, that is, $\Gamma^T\Gamma x = \Gamma^Tb$. Have a look on the residual in the first problem instead (in normal equations).